# buildConfig.groovy compile / runtime dependency performance

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Simply a concern I had about performance when having more and more plugins being added into the `BuildConfig.groovy` file.  My concern is, how often would these plugins be downloaded and installed?  Would it be on every instance of the app, i.e. once per user?  Would it be once per application lifecycle?  Or would it be only ever once?  Or other?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the type of dependency you have:

> Typically, dependencies are constant. That is, for a given combination of group, name and version the jar (or plugin) that it refers to will never change. The Grails dependency management system uses this fact to cache dependencies in order to avoid having to download them from the source repository each time. Sometimes this is not desirable. For example, many developers use the convention of a snapshot (i.e. a dependency with a version number ending in “-SNAPSHOT”) that can change from time to time while still retaining the same version number. We call this a "changing dependency".

Further details in the grails documentation about [dependency resolution](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#changingDependencies)